# How to run a loop inside a jsx string set using dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to run loop like this

```
const items = [{name: 'nice'},{ name: 'bice'}, {name: 'tice'}]
 const stringJsx = `
 <ol>
    ${
      items.map((item, index) =>{
        return (
          <li key={index}>this is a nice item : ${item.name}</li>
        )
      })
    }
</ol>
return (
 <>
    
    <h1 id='nice'> this is a nice h1 tag</h1>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: stringJsx }} />
    
 </>
 )
`
```

I sm `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` as result. How can I run conditions, loop and other things from a jsx as a string?

I need this jsx as string and will be stored in a db.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want it to be a string, you must return a string inside the `map()`, not a html element, change the `stringJsx` to something like:

```js
const stringJsx = (`
    <ol>
        ${
            items.map((item, index) => {
                return `<li key=${index}>this is a nice item : ${item.name}</li>`;
            }).join('')
        }
    </ol>
`);
```

Btw: consider using [`join('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) after the map so there won't be any `,`'s in between the `<li>`'s

Full snippet using the above code:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {    
    render() {

        const items = [{name: 'nice'},{ name: 'bice'}, {name: 'tice'}];
        const stringJsx = (`
            <ol>
                ${
                    items.map((item, index) => {
                        return `<li key=${index}>this is a nice item : ${item.name}</li>`;
                    }).join('')
                }
            </ol>
        `);
        
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1 id='nice'> this is a nice h1 tag</h1>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: stringJsx }} />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body);
```

```css
:root{
    --bg-clr-1: #E7F8F8;
    --card-clr-red: #F03E3E;
    --card-clr-violet: #7950F2;
    --card-clr-green: #12B886;
    --text-clr: #333;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

###### Edit:

Another snippet, based on [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515475/how-to-run-a-loop-inside-a-jsx-string-set-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml/71515600?noredirect=1#comment126400477_71515600), without `join()`. I've used [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the same behaviour;

```js
const stringJsx = items.reduce((prev, cur, index) => (
    prev + `<li key=${index}>this is a nice item : ${cur.name}</li>`
), '');
```

```js
class Example extends React.Component {    
    render() {

        const items = [{name: 'nice'},{ name: 'bice'}, {name: 'tice'}];
        const stringJsx = items.reduce((prev, cur, index) => (
            prev + `<li key=${index}>this is a nice item : ${cur.name}</li>`
        ), '');
        
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1 id='nice'> this is a nice h1 tag</h1>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: stringJsx }} />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body);
```

```css
:root{
    --bg-clr-1: #E7F8F8;
    --card-clr-red: #F03E3E;
    --card-clr-violet: #7950F2;
    --card-clr-green: #12B886;
    --text-clr: #333;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: No other ways to use the loop without having an extra `,` at the end? Writing `.join('')` at the end of each return is problematic. Thank you.

Comment: Please see my edit. I've added another snippet using `reduce` so `join` isn't needed.